# What's the trick to getting systemd automounts working on 16.04?

Tags: systemd

I was focusing on my 17.10 system as I tinkered with systemd automounts. My goal was to have my CIFS share automount, much like AutoFS does. This was accomplished on 17.10 with the following configs (via pastebin) and everything works fine. No issues to report. http://paste.ubuntu.com/26062465/

I copied those unit files to my wife's 17.10 system. In half a minute I was up and running. No issues.

I copied those unit files to my 16.04 system. Hours later, I still can't get it to work. The status of the service says it's active and waiting. Green light. Everything looks good to go. But when I navigate to that share with either Nautilus or via CD'ing to it in terminal, it just hangs -- forever. For kicks I tried the same thing on another laptop I have running Ubuntu Mate 16.04. Same exact scenario there.

I've gone over the unit files and cannot figure out where the crossup is. The only difference I'm seeing is 16.04 has systemd version 229, and 17.10 has systemd version 234. Could this be the difference? I had trouble when searching to see if there was an explicit version of systemd that implemented the particular functionality (automount) I'm after.

Anybody have any guesses or insight?

One last thing to confirm -- yes, cifs-utils is installed.

Comment: Eh, maybe it's simply not possible in 16.04. I figured since systemd wasn't barking at me with errors and I had the green light in status that I was on to something. I ended up digging around more and found this Phoronix article, which reads "Systemd Rolls Out Its Own Mount Tool -- Systemd-mount was added to systemd Git yesterday and will be part of the upcoming systemd 232 release." Given 16.04 is on version 229 of systemd, I assume this is the culprit. Source: https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Systemd-Mount

Comment: remember linux isn't really about upgrades.  the top level is mostly just a GUI so you don't really need to upgrade that often and be careful.  to be honest the top level has just changed a few details in the past few years and not much else at least in ubuntu.  I too am frustrasted with constant updates.

Comment: If anything I wouldn't mind having some more updates about now, such as an update of systemd to a version 232 or newer so I could get automount shares to work on 16.04 :D :D

Comment: I guess the only remaining question I would have is... I understand that things get backported to older versions, however I'm curious if 'features' such as this (as opposed to bug fixes) would have made it down to the v229 of systemd that Ubuntu packages. Initial impression is no, but I'm not sure how I'd be able to confirm that.

Comment: to be honest I'm not sure.  you would need to look at the diff on the files and unfortunatly the view I have is that during a system update it would be interesting to view the diffs.  Great idea...!  LIVE DIFF view during updates!